# JTree single node foreground

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtree, highlighting

I know this question has been asked before in a similar way, maybe for icons.
What I'm trying is to change the color of the text of the tree node.
In fact, I have a jTree and I will want to set up three differents colors, default one, red and orange.

The purposse, is that if I compare that tree with another one, highlight differences between both trees (default means no diff, orange means just value diff and red means node is complete different)

I have two functions, one which trasverse the "original" tree looking for a node from the compared one, and returns false if {node} is not found:

```
private Boolean findNodeInRefTree(DefaultTreeModel model, Object root, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
     Boolean bRet = false;
     for (int i = 0; ((i < model.getChildCount(root))&&(!bRet)); i++){
         DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getChild(root, i);
         bRet = node.getUserObject().equals(child.getUserObject());
         if (!bRet)
             bRet = findNodeInRefTree(model, child, node);
     }//for:i
     return bRet;
}
```

And another function that trasverse the "compare" tree and calls the above for each node.

```
private void compareTrees(TreeModel model, Object root){

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getChildCount(root); i++){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getChild(root, i);        
        //find if node exists in original
        DefaultTreeModel modelRef = (DefaultTreeModel) _ref.getModel();
        if (!findNodeInRefTree(modelRef, modelRef.getRoot(), child)){
            DefaultTreeCellRenderer render = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) _temp.getCellRenderer();
            render.setForeground(Color.RED);
            _temp.setCellRenderer(render);
        }//fi            
        _new.insertNodeInto((DefaultMutableTreeNode) child, (DefaultMutableTreeNode) root, i);            
        compareTrees(model, child);
    }//for:i
}
```

Then, when it ends I just set the model of the new tree {_new} to the new tree {_temp}, and add the tree to its panel. But the tree doesn't has any different color. Obviously, I'm testing with different trees. Any suggestion?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, your do the comparison at creation time and set the renderer for each tree node (i.e. multiple times) inside method `compareTrees`.

Unfortunately, that is not the way [tree renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) are handled in swing. The renderer is prepared on request during rendering the tree component. Thus setting multiple renderer beforehand won't do anything useful.

A possible approach would be to do the comparison and save the result (i.e. color) in your tree model. You can then write a basic tree renderer which reads this value for the current node and sets the rendering color accordingly.

Comment: In fact, first I load two trees from different sources (XML files)
Then, I walk through the second one, which is the one I compare with the first tree, and based on the differences I built another temporal tree that removes the second.